# Confirming a maven project converted to web app is created correctly

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, tomcat7, m2e

When I convert a maven project to a web project (by updating checking the box "Dynamic Web Module" in project facets)  the project I convert does not contain the dynamic web app icon. Should the icon be present ? How can I confirm that the project is converted to a web app project correctly ?

Dynamic web icon missing
[image: Dynamic web icon missing]

Dynamic web icon present
[image: Dynamic web icon present]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did exactly this and here is what it looks like after you add the facet in Eclipse Indigo (sorry for the blackout):

[image]

As you can see the little circular icon overlay is not on the top level project node, but on the nodes underneath.  It was kinda cool how WTP automatically took my web.xml and created the helpful "Deployment Descriptor" node for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maven icon ('M') seems to be laying on top of the dynamic web module icon (the globe icon).  By converting the project to non-maven, thus removing the 'M' icon, you get the globe icon.

IMHO, Maven overlay should move over from the upper-left corner on the project folder icon to lower-left corner or something..